# How to listen onClick events on complex Images on Android

Tags: android, webview, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I have the following image:

[image]

I need to change the color of the circles once it is clicked.

- The image is a SVG
- Should work on Android API 17+ and if possible for tablets as well

What is a smart/effective way to achieve that?

The possible solution I have until now are:

1. Break it in small clickable parts(Not good, there will be lots of images, other body parts will be required to do the same)
2. Use a Webview with Javascript to change the colors.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: set this image as parent views Background and make Buttons as child
though you need to design it for different sizes!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use WebView and handle with these click events you need using javascript or even JQuery. You just need to put ID or classes.

```
$("#cicleButton1").click(function() {
});
```

Comment: can you please be more specific please?

Comment: For sure, have you ever work with HTML and JS? If the answer is Yes you know that you can put "Id" and "class" into the elements. This also apply for SVG elements, you will find the rect that correspond to where you want to click and add an "ID" like "cicleButton1". Your JS will have the code I sent you above and when user click into the element you added the ID will fire the JS event.
Into your Android Project you ill need to listen the webview events, you can easily find how to do this in Google.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Pantaleão, I will keep that in mind :D